# POST to GET Scenario, method body to query string parameter

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I think I hit an AWS API Gateway scenario that doesn't appear to have a solution.

I am trying to create a json POST endpoint to validate an address against a USPS service.

The ultimate request looks like this:

http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="***SECRET***"><Address><Address1>101 Foo Lane</Address1></Address2><City>Somewhereville</City><State>CA</State><Zip5>90210</Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>

The issue I'm having is I need to set the XML query string parameter based on my passed in method body, e.g.:

{
  address: "101 Foo Lane",
  city: "Somewhereville",
  state: "CA",
  zip: "90210"
}

It appears in the Integration Request, I can specify the "Mapped from", but I can't access the method body, only the method.request.{"path", "querystring" | "header"}.{param_name}

Also there doesn't appear for me to construct a param_name value in the Method Request setup from the incoming method body.

The XML to JSON response mapping is working great if I provide a hard coded XML query string, so I'm down to just the request mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the body to request parameter using `method.request.body.JSONPath_EXPRESSION` but you can't construct the request parameter using a template similar to what can be done for integration request body. All the available mappings are documented here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html